# View Saved query data in Sub form - Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to view the data in sub-form. Below is the code which I am trying.

```
Dim qdfretriveVal As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim strQry As String

Set qdfretriveVal = CurrentDb.QueryDef("export_excel")
Set rs = qdfretriveVal(14)

rs.OpenRecordset
DoCmd.OpenQuery "export_excel", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
```

In Access I have saved "export_excel" query as per following.

```
PARAMETERS val Long;
SELECT Raw_Data_New.A, Raw_Data_New.B, Raw_Data_New.Val
FROM Raw_Data_New
WHERE (((Raw_Data_New.Val)=[val]));
```

I want to pass the parameter val and view the data in Subform. can any one assist me, how to achieve this output?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to do this is

- Create a form with the query you want to display as the Record Source. Do not put any filter on here. No parameters. Nothing. Let it display all the data.
- Put your new form as a subform on your main form.
- Add a control like a combo box or a bound control (however you want to get the data) and link it to `val` (what was your parameter)
- in the subform's properties go to Data > Link Master Fields > your textbox/combobox/whatever from previous bullet.
- then Data > Link Child Fields > `Val`

Now your subform will be filtered based on your parent form but with no parameters.